# How can I use map with formik and React components to create a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Sorry to ask, but I'm having trouble using map with formik and a custom react component. Specifically,
I'm passing a particular entry in a list of objects to a component,

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    name: "default",
    //thing: "",
    questions: [
      { qText: "defQ", answers: ["", ""], correct: 1 },
    ],
  }}
  onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    console.log(data, "HYH");
    data.questions.push("");
    data.answers.push(["", ""]);
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
>
  {({
    values,
    isSubmitting,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
  }) => (
    <Form>
      <FieldArray name="questions">
        {({ push, remove }) => (
          <>
            <div>
              {values.questions.map((que, qI) => {
                return (
                  <QComp
                    question={que}
                    qIndex={qI}
                    remove={remove}
                    values={values}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <Button
              type="button"
              onClick={() =>
                push({
                  qText: "",
                  answers: ["", ""],
                  correct: 1,
                })
              }
            >
              Add Question
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
      </FieldArray>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

```
    function QComp({ values, question, qIndex, remove }) {
  return (
    <div
      key={`qBox${qIndex}`}
      style={{
        border: "2px solid green",
        width: "25%",
        margin: "50px 50px 50px 33%",
      }}
    >
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>

      <Field
        name={`questions.qText`}
        style={{
          margin: "20px 10px 60px 66px",
          width: "60%",
        }}
        as={TextField}
      />
      <div key={`answers${qIndex}`}>
        <FieldArray
          name={`values.question[${qIndex}].answers`}
        >
          {({ push, remove }) => (
            <div>
              {question.answers.map((answer, aI) => {
                {
                  console.log(question.correct, "Bingo");
                }
                return (
                  <AComp
                    answer={answer}
                    aIndex={aI}
                    correct={question.correct}
                    remove={remove}
                  ></AComp>
                );
              })}
              <Button
                type="button"
                //variant="contained"
                onClick={() => push("")}
              >
                {""}
                Add Answer{""}
              </Button>
            </div>
          )}
        </FieldArray>
      </div>
      <Button type="button" onClick={() => remove(qIndex)}>
        Remove Question
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function AComp({
  qIndex,
  aIndex,
  correct,
  remove,
}) {
  return (
    <div key={`${qIndex}ans${aIndex}div`}>
      <Field
        name={`answer`}
        style={{
          margin: "0px 0px 0px 15px",
        }}
        as={TextField}
      />
      <Field
        id={`radio${qIndex}num${aIndex}`}
        key={`radio${qIndex}num${aIndex}`}
        //id={`radio${qIndex}num${aIndex}`}
        name={`correct`}
        value={aIndex}
        type="radio"
        checked={aIndex == correct}
        as={Radio}
      ></Field>
      <Button
        type="button"
        //variant="contained"
        onClick={() => remove(aIndex)}
      >
        Remove Answer
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I make changes to the text field, the object either isn't modified at all (like in the first field under QComp), or gets a new field, totally separate from the one I'm trying to modify, such as the first field under AComp. Can anyone  help me fix this, or come up with a better way to have map with a formik form like this? I have a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-framework-946i9?file=/src/Quizzes.js:5304-5310

Comment: Can you point out which text field are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, the first field inside the AComp function, with name `answer`. it needs to change the answer parameter that was passed to it inside the QComp function (with a map) but instead it's adding a field called answer to the object.

Comment: You have passed "answer" as props in <AComp> and expecting qIndex in props of  function AComp({
  qIndex,
  aIndex,
  correct,
  remove,
}).

Comment: Its rendering the component as required. Replace the empty strings by null.

Comment: I fixed the arguments, but nothing has improved. Could you explain what you mean by replacing the empty strings by null?